# how to return input values as response value in wso2 data service

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am using Mac OS-X 10.7.5 and wso2 esb 4.0.3 with data service(3.2.3) feature added in it.
I have created a wso2 data service which is working fine.But now I have to implement  a ping operation in this data service which will check the health of service. This opertaion will get a message as input and will return the 'input value' with some message as output.But I am not getting  how to return input value as responce.
Ping opeartion Request xml :
        
         InputVALUE

Ping Responce xml: 
        
         InputValue 
         "Success"
        
How I can set 'responce data' at wso2 data service level. Request and Responce xml is mentioned in next comment.Please help me on this.
Thanks,Saurabh

Comment: Ping opeartion Request xml :
        <GttData>
        <Message> InputVALUE </Message>
        </GttData>

Ping Responce xml: 
        <GttDataResponce>
        <statuscode> InputValue </statusCode>
        <statusMessage> "Success"</statusMessage>
        </GttDataResponce>

Answer (score 1):

this walkaround will help you if your database is ORACLE. If not, try to get a similar SQL.

The query definition would be like this:

```
<query id="Ping" useConfig="default">
   <sql>SELECT 'OK' OK FROM DUAL</sql>
   <result defaultNamespace="resultNamespace" element="PingResponse">
      <element column="OK" name="Result" xsdType="xs:string"/>
   </result> 
</query>
```

I have test it and the result is

```
<PingResponse xmlns="resultNamespace">
 <Result>OK</Result>
</PingResponse>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: But we have to return the 2 values from data service.(1)incoming value to data service as Status Message and (2) Status code(hardcoded).So for returning same value as came in request from data service,I am not getting any solution. And for how to use context variable please suggest a link or document.

Comment: I think the only way to do that is getting by with sql and stored procedures. I cannot figure out another way with the resources that offer wso2 dss. Here you have a despcription of the options availables http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/DSS300/Data+Services+and+Resources. The good practice for this is implement it in the ESB.

Comment: Thanks Fipries.Applied your suggestion and got success.

Answer (score 0):

you could create another proxy service which calls the dss service. When dss service response is ok, you compose the response with input values which previously you have stored in a context variable.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for help fipries.But the Problem is  I have one requirement according to that I have to create a data service which will have one query for business means it will return 16 fields by interacting with DB and for Ping it is just for checking the health of the service.So I think it should not interact with DB ,then how we will get the "OK" message from data service in proxy .Can you please give some more help.